# QML performance issue

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've faced with bad performance issue in my qml(windows, v5,15.2) application. I profiled it and 50% of time my app is in the following thread with call stack:

```
"Functions (for Thread-1572 (TID 1572))"    "Timer samples (s)"
"QV4::MemoryManager::collectRoots(struct QV4::MarkStack *)" 9.00%
"markChildQObjectsRecursively"  5.29%
"QV4::MemoryManager::mark(void)"    4.96%
"QStatePrivate::q_func(void)"   4.54%
"QObject::parent(void)" 4.14%
"QListData::begin(void)"    2.63%
"QV4::Heap::QObjectWrapper::markObjects(struct QV4::Heap::Base *,struct QV4::MarkStack *)"  2.14%
"QV4::Heap::Object::markObjects(struct QV4::Heap::Base *,struct QV4::MarkStack *)"  1.59%
"QV4::Heap::QQuickItemWrapper::markObjects(struct QV4::Heap::Base *,struct QV4::MarkStack *)"   1.41%
"QV4::QObjectWrapper::markWrapper(class QObject *,struct QV4::MarkStack *)" 1.15%
"QtMetaTypePrivate::QSequentialIterableImpl::sizeImpl&lt;class QList&lt;class QModelIndex&gt; &gt;(void const *)"   1.15%
"QV4::Value::mark(struct QV4::MarkStack *)" 1.03%
"QV4::Heap::QObjectWrapper::object(void)"   0.98%
"QV4::PersistentValueStorage::mark(struct QV4::MarkStack *)"    0.72%
"QV4::IdentifierHashData::markObjects(struct QV4::MarkStack *)" 0.63%
"QV4::PersistentValueStorage::Iterator::operator++(void)"   0.57%
"QQmlVMEMetaObject::mark(struct QV4::MarkStack *)"  0.54%
"QV4::MemoryManager::sweep(bool,void (*)(char const *))"    0.50%
"QV4::Heap::ExecutionContext::markObjects(struct QV4::Heap::Base *,struct QV4::MarkStack *)"    0.44%
"QV4::ValueArray&lt;32&gt;::mark(struct QV4::MarkStack *)"  0.44%
```

Why memory manager takes so much time? What the reason of such behaviour and how could I increase performance?
Most of the time my application receives json in c++(it is often a very huge object contains base64 jpeg image), than parse it is to QVariantMap, than emit signal with parsed map and handle it signal in qml

Comment: It's hard to give you a good answer since we don't know what your application is doing. This particular call stack looks like it is doing garbage collection.

Comment: @JarMan, thank you for reply, most of the time my application receives json in c++(it is often a very huge object contains base64 jpeg image), than parse it is to QVariantMap, than emit signal with parsed map and handle it signal in qml

Comment: If you're passing very large json objects to QML, maybe that's why the garbage collection is taking so long. I really have no way to know for sure. Do you have to pass the whole object to QML? Maybe just some metadata would be sufficient?

Comment: @JarMan c++ is only a receiver, qml decide what to do with a specific message, it could deal with it by himself, or could pass some nested object to another receivers(qml or c++)